How do I fix an error while building Godot
I am attempting to build Godot and while doing that I got this error
ERROR: modules\register_module_types.gen.cpp: In function 'void initialize_modules(ModuleInitializationLevel)':
modules\register_module_types.gen.cpp:182:9: error: 'initialize_node1d_module' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'initialize_noise_module'?
  182 |         initialize_node1d_module(p_level);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |         initialize_noise_module
modules\register_module_types.gen.cpp: In function 'void uninitialize_modules(ModuleInitializationLevel)':
modules\register_module_types.gen.cpp:341:9: error: 'uninitialize_node1d_module' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'uninitialize_noise_module'?
  341 |         uninitialize_node1d_module(p_level);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |         uninitialize_noise_module

I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find anything. Any help would be appreciated.
Image of the file tree for the modules/node1d folder:

looks like a header file not being included.

@MatsWichmann do you mean in the modules folder or in the node1d folder?

Godot has a fairly involved build system, and it is only really actively maintained for a couple of compilers. What OS and compiler are you using? (And how are you invoking the build?)

@Dúthomhas I'm using windows and SCons
I'm invoking it (if I understand your usage of that word correctly) via the CMD command python -m SCons custom_modules=modules/node1d platform=windows

That is not an approved method of invoking scons for compiling Godot. (Docs) I assume you have properly added Node1D (or are using a dedicated branch) to the source tree (I presume in the modules subdirectory). Just dropping it there is not enough! Also, you haven’t mentioned your compiler.

I was able to fix the problem by renaming the node1d file to 1d.
I believe that this worked because in the register_types file the initialize function is initialize_1d_module() and the generator takes the name of the folder so changing the folder name solved the problem.
